# IPC::Run timeout doesn't work

Tags: perl

Goal: Perl script that runs Revit (or any executable) and timesout if runs too long.  I've got it to run Revit but can't seem to add a timeout or use the other versions of run with arguments $in $out $err

Windows environment.

Below is the one "run" that works and the results of others that don't work at all, especially the one I'd like where I can specify a timeout.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );
my $revitPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Revit 2016\\Revit.exe"; 

#I think I need quotes because there are spaces in the line
my $revitExe = "\"$revitPath\"";
my @cmd1 = "\"$revitPath\"";
#don't think I need any arguments, just want to start it for now and time out. 
my $in = "";
my ($out, $err);

#Here We're Happy, runs Revit:
run @cmd1;

#All the following:  Not Happy:

#This one just seems to do nothing, no complaints, just does nothing
#----->  This is the main goal.  I want to time out Revit if it runs too long.
run @cmd1, timeout(40000) or die "cat: $?";
#----->

#This one says "file not found: "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe" at line 16
run \@cmd1;

#This one says 
   #Unexpected SCALAR(0x1d21adc) in harness() parameter 3 at example.pl line 21
   #Unexpected SCALAR(0x1d21acc) in harness() parameter 4 at example.pl line 21
run @cmd1, \$in, \$out, \$err;

#This one says "file not found: "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe" at line 24
run @cmd1, $in, $out, $err;

print "out: $out\n";
print "err: $err\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell it to execute a file named

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe"
```

but the file is named

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe
```

Replace

```
my @cmd1 = "\"$revitPath\"";
run \@cmd1, ...
```

with

```
my @cmd1 = $revitPath;
run \@cmd1, ...
```

or

```
run [ $revitPath ],  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Totally worked.   (obviously a perl newb) I'll be over in the corner with my dunce cap on.